# PHP eCommerce categories structure explained

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a simple online shop using PHP and mysql.

I need to understand the relation of categories to the products!

I have created a Table in mysql database called "categories" and 2 columns in that table called "`cat_id`" and "`cat_name`".

I have also created a Table that holds the products and its called "`products`" and two columns called "`product_id`" and "`product_name`".

now I need to know how I can link these two tables together?

could someone please clarify this for me please?

Comment: you would need to have a cat_id in your product table as well.

Comment: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323748/database-design-items-in-category-sub-category-theme/20324888#20324888) I believe it covers what you need

Comment: Depends if a product can be inside only one or more categories. In the first case (only one) add a foreign key into products which is a reference to categories (cat_id). In the other case you need a relation table with one product_id and cat_id on each line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join two tables mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

If products can have *many* categories and categories can be assigned to *many* products. It's a `ManyToMany` relationship and therefore requires a link table.

I would create a table `product_category` with columns `product_id` and `category_id`

If a product can only have one category, you could add it as a foreign key to the product table as a column such as `category_id`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your concept. Can products reside in more than one category at a time? If so, you'll need a link table. Otherwise, you can simply add a column to your `products` table, which contains the ID of the category in which it resides.

The former is more complicated since it involves a many-to-many relationship, which is something you should be avoiding as part of your normalization. You'd need to have a link table that looks something like this:

```
+------------+------------+----------+----------+
|   cat_id   |   prod_id  |  active  |   order  |
+------------+------------+----------+----------+
|     1      |     1      |    1     |     0    |
|     1      |     2      |    0     |     1    |
|     2      |     2      |    1     |     0    |
+------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

As you can see, we have four columns (you might only need two):

- `cat_id` is the ID of the category (from `categories`)
- `prod_id` is the ID of the product (from `products`)
- `active` is a boolean value which indicates whether the product is currently active in this category
- `order` defines the sort order of this product for the given category

In the sample data above, product ID 1 and 2 both appear in Category 1. However, Product ID 2 is not active. Product ID 2 also appears as the only product in Category 2.